# Xamarin.Froms - Instantiate 2 services in viewmodel constructor

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Fairly new to xamarin.forms, so sorry if this is a silly question.

I'm trying to instantiate two custom services in my viewmodels constructor, like this:

**Updated*

***HerdDetailsViewModel***

```
public class HerdDetailsViewModel : ViewModelBase, INavigationAware
{
    private Herd herd;
    private readonly IHerdService herdService;
    private readonly IHerdUserInfoService herdUserInfoService;

    public Herd Herd { 
            get => herd;
            set => SetProperty(ref herd, value);
        }
    private HerdUserInfo herdUserInfo;
    public HerdUserInfo HerdUserInfo
    {
        get => herdUserInfo;
        set => SetProperty(ref herdUserInfo, value);
    }
 
   
    public HerdDetailsViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IHerdService herdService, IHerdUserInfoService herdUserInfoService) 
        : base(navigationService)
    {
        this.herdService = herdService;
        this.herdUserInfoService = herdUserInfoService;
        
    }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);

        Herd = parameters.GetValue<Herd>("herd");
        
    }
```

INavigationService is a reference to the Prism Library for navigation.

For some reason, i now cant open a specific contentpage.
After i've made the instantiation of the *HerdUserInfoService*

***HerdService & HerdUserInfoService*** just returns hard coded objects.

Please, can someone enlighten me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What library are you using for the dependency injection?

Comment: @Ardit I dont use any libaries for dependency injection. I simply use the set method, to add data to my test objects.

Comment: What are `INavigationService` and  `IHerdService` in your project ? Post the full code .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Have made some corrections. Hopefully makes it clearer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found the answer.

For some reason it worked by setting to a new instance like this:

```
private readonly IHerdUserInfoService herdUserInfoService = new HerdUserInfoService();
```